# Filling unordered_set is too slow

Tags: c++, performance, unordered-set

We have a given 3D-mesh and we are trying to eliminate identical vertexes. For this we are using a self defined struct containing the coordinates of a vertex and the corresponding normal.

```
    struct vertice
    {
        float p1,p2,p3,n1,n2,n3;

        bool operator == (const vertice& vert) const
        {
            return (p1 == vert.p1 && p2 == vert.p2 && p3 == vert.p3);
        }
    };
```

After filling the vertex with data, it is added to an unordered_set to remove the duplicates.

```
    struct hashVertice
    {
        size_t operator () (const vertice& vert) const
        {
            return(7*vert.p1 + 13*vert.p2 + 11*vert.p3);
        }
    };

    std::unordered_set<vertice,hashVertice> verticesSet;

    vertice vert;

    while(i<(scene->mMeshes[0]->mNumVertices)){

            vert.p1 = (float)scene->mMeshes[0]->mVertices[i].x;
            vert.p2 = (float)scene->mMeshes[0]->mVertices[i].y;
            vert.p3 = (float)scene->mMeshes[0]->mVertices[i].z;

            vert.n1 = (float)scene->mMeshes[0]->mNormals[i].x;
            vert.n2 = (float)scene->mMeshes[0]->mNormals[i].y;
            vert.n3 = (float)scene->mMeshes[0]->mNormals[i].z;

            verticesSet.insert(vert);

            i = i+1;
    }
```

We discovered that it is too slow for data amounts like 3.000.000 vertexes. Even after 15 minutes of running the program wasn't finished. Is there a bottleneck we don't see or is another data structure better for such a task?

Comment: If the p1,p2,p3 values are all small, then the hash function will return near-zero values for all points and performance will be very slow.

Comment: Have you tried letting it use the standard hashing? Is it faster or slower?

Comment: Obvious question... Have you enabled optimization in the compiler?

Comment: You want to use a hash function with at least some degree of avalanche effect. Otherwise you may observe the performance of a linked list in the worst case. Which will render common set operation quite inefficient.

Comment: Thanks to interjay! Improving the hash function using larger primes solved the problem.

Comment: Also have a look at this list of hash functions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What happens if you just remove `verticesSet.insert(vert);` from the loop?

If it speeds-up dramatically (as I expect it would), your bottleneck is in the guts of the `std::unordered_set`, which is a hash-table, and the main potential performance problem with hash tables is when there are excessive hash **collisions**.

In your current implementation, if `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are **small**, the number of distinct hash codes will be small (since you "collapse" float to integer) and there will be lots of collisions.

If the above assumptions turn out to be true, I'd try to implement the hash function differently (e.g. multiply with much larger coefficients).

---

Other than that, profile your code, as others have already suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Hashing floating point can be tricky.  In particular, your hash
routine calculates the hash as a floating point value, then
converts it to an unsigned integral type.  This has serious
problems if the vertices can be small: if all of the vertices
are in the range `[0...1.0)`, for example, your hash function
will never return anything greater than 13.  As an unsigned
integer, which means that there will be at most 13 different
hash codes.

The usual way to hash floating point is to hash the binary
image, checking for the special cases first.  (`0.0` and `-0.0`
have different binary images, but must hash the same.  And it's
an open question what you do with `NaN`s.)  For `float` this is
particularly simple, since it usually has the same size as
`int`, and you can `reinterpret_cast`:

```
size_t
hash( float f )
{
    assert( /* not a NaN */ );
    return f == 0.0 ? 0.0 : reinterpret_cast( unsigned& )( f );
}
```

I know, formally, this is undefined behavior.  But if float and
int have the same size, and unsigned has no trapping
representations (the case on most general purpose machines
today), then a compiler which gets this wrong is being
intentionally obtuse.

You then use any combining algorithm to merge the three results;
the one you use is as good as any other (in this case—it's
not a good generic algorithm).

I might add that while some of the comments insist on profiling
(and this is generally good advice), if you're taking 15 minutes
for 3 million values, the problem can really only be a poor hash
function, which results in lots of collisions.  Nothing else will
cause that bad of performance.  And unless you're familiar with
the internal implementation of `std::unordered_set`, the usual
profiler output will probably not give you much information.
On the other hand, `std::unordered_set` does have functions
like `bucket_count` and `bucket_size`, which allow analysing
the quality of the hash function.  In your case, if you cannot
create an `unordered_set` with 3 million entries, your first
step should be to create a much smaller one, and use these
functions to evaluate the quality of your hash code.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a bottleneck, you are definitely not seeing it, because you don't include any kind of timing measures.

Measure the timing of your algorithm, either with a profiler or just manually. This will let you find the bottleneck - if there is one.

This is the correct way to proceed. Expecting yourself, or alternatively, StackOverflow users to spot bottlenecks by eye inspection instead of actually measuring time in your program is, from my experience, the most common cause of failed attempts at optimization.

Comment: This is generally correct, but supposing a typical general purpose machine... the only thing which could possibly account for the performance he describes is a poor hashing function.  (Which isn't easy to identify in profiler output, unless you're familiar with the internals of the hash table itself.)

Comment: @JamesKanze I agree. But this doesn't rule out the need for actually measuring time.

Comment: Well, he's measured that it takes more than a quarter of an hour to fill the `unordered_set`.  Given that, I'd start by creating a much smaller set, and using `bucket_count` and `bucket_size` to evaluate the quality of my hash function.  (If you find something like 100000 buckets, and only 15 or 20 which aren't empty, you know what the problem is.)